# Why is parse(text=) throwing an error when there is a comma in the text?

Tags: r, shiny

Inside of a Shiny app I am combining levels to make a ID that will be used for ggplot faceting.

Here is an example of what works when doing it by hand:
`paste0(data[[1]],', ',data[[2]])`

However, the user can select whatever and how ever many identifying columns they want, so I am automating it like this:

First I build combo_ID_build from whatever columns they have selected in UI1 (which is numeric with column numbers for whatever the user selected).

```
         for (i in UI1){
           combo_ID_build<-paste0(combo_ID_build,"data[[",i,"]]")
           if(i != tail(UI1,1)){
             combo_ID_build<-paste0(combo_ID_build,",', ',")
           }
         }
```

Then I use eval(parse())

`ID <- paste0(eval(parse(text = combo_ID_build)))`

So for this example, the user selects columns 1 and 2, so combo_ID_build would be `"data[[1]],', ',data[[2]]"` where str(combo_ID_build) is chr.

However, when parsed this throws an error, "Error in parse(text = combo_ID_build) : :1:10: unexpected ','
1: data[[1]],"

I tried escaping the comma with \ and \\ but it only throws an error about the backslashes being unrecognized escape strings.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `eval(parse())` tries to parse and evaluate an expression. You run

```
eval(parse(text = "data[[1]],', ',data[[2]]"))
```

That's equivalent to running the command

```
data[[1]], ', ', data[[2]]
```

which indeed is a syntax error. It doesn't matter that you wrapped it in `paste0`, when you have `foo(bar())` `foo()` will run on the output of `bar()`. If `bar()` can't run on its own, there will be an error. You have `paste0(eval(parse())`, `paste0()` will run on the output of `eval()`. So what you `eval()` needs to run on its own before `paste0()` is called.

`eval(parse())` should usually be avoided. In this case, I think you're looking for `do.call`, which lets you call a function on a set of arguments in a `list`. Let's also use `paste` with `sep = ", "` to simplify things:

```
# no loop or eval/parse needed
combo_ID_build = do.call(what = \(x) paste(x, sep = ", "), args = data[UI1])
```

In this particular case, we can simplify even more by using the utility function `interaction()` which is made for this use case:

```
combo_ID_build = interaction(data[UI1], sep = ", ")
```

I'll leave you with this:

```
fortunes::fortune(106)
# If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
#    -- Thomas Lumley
#       R-help (February 2005)
```

Comment: Aha, I think you have helped me to understand that better. I am just and engineer and statistician, so your solution is astonishing to me. Thank you!